# brew install python3 didn't install pip3

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pip, homebrew

I installed python3 using homebrew but it didn't install pip3 or should I say it installed but it doesn't recognize the command ?

Here is what I did:

```
brew install python3
```

This installed python3 but threw an error at the end saying it couldn't link python3 and prompted me to run

```
brew link python3
```

to link the installation but this throws another error:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3... Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/lib
```

Does anyone know how solve this ? 
When I run:

```
brew info python3
```

It says:

```
==> Caveats
Pip, setuptools, and wheel have been installed. To update them
  pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

You can install Python packages with
  pip3 install <package>

They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

See: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python.html
```

Which makes me think pip3 is installed but not recognized. Any help is appreciated.

INFO:

OS => MacOS High Sierra 10.13.1

```
 pip3 install twilio
-bash: pip3: command not found
```

Comment: My gut says you wouldn't require `pip3` as `pip` picks up your currently active version of python depending on your environment.

Comment: My `pip3` is here `/usr/local/bin/pip3`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Ok it took me a lot of googling but the problem is that in high sierra all permissions inside usr/local changed and homebrew has to create some folder inside usr/local. Here is how I solved everything:

> I tried using `sudo brew install python3` but that also threw an error
>   directly from Homebrew telling me that it doesn't allow the use of
>   `sudo brew`.

**Create the folders I needed using sudo mkdir inside /usr/local:**

```
sudo mkdir lib 
sudo mkdir Frameworks
```

**Change the permissions inside /usr/local so that homebrew can access them:**

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

**Now install python3**

```
brew install python3
```

**This will give you a successful installation:**

```
==> Pouring python3-3.6.3.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/bin/python3 -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install --force --verbose --install-scripts=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/bin --in
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/bin/python3 -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install --force --verbose --install-scripts=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/bin --in
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/bin/python3 -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install --force --verbose --install-scripts=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/bin --in
==> Caveats
Pip, setuptools, and wheel have been installed. To update them
  pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

You can install Python packages with
  pip3 install <package>

They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

See: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python.html
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3: 3,588 files, 56.1MB
```

Comment: "in high sierra all permissions inside usr/local changed" Do you have a source on that? I haven’t got any issue upgrading to High Sierra.

Comment: I read this on github: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3228 And when I listed the usr/local directory, most of the folders needed "root" access. After creating all the folder which brew can't create because I can't run "sudo brew" I changed permission to from "root" to  "me" and brew works now fine.

Comment: An update -  I have created one more folder on my machine, *local/opt*. Then executed the permission commands. It is perfectly working (python3+pip3) now. Thanks for the Q&A.

Comment: awesome, you saved my day!

Comment: Sadly, having to do something like this to fix homebrew defeats the whole purpose of homebrew to begin with.

Comment: After following the steps, had to run `brew reinstall python3` for pip3 to be installed

Comment: `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*` when in `/usr/local` folder it appears to change permissions on ALL my system's folders. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 12):

After resolving the linking issue (e.g. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/19286 ), python3 is installed but not pip3. Reinstalling python (e.g. brew reinstall python) eventually installs pip3 as well. These steps works well for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this fixed the issue:

```
brew unlink python@3.9; brew link python@3.9
```

(You might have to replace the version number with the version you have installed)

Comment: This doesn't work for me on centos 7

Answer (score 1):

GitHub user @aether2501, [commenting](https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/7732946#gistcomment-2298740) on a sudo chown solution for a "Homebrew Permission Denied" [problem](https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/7732946#file-homebrew-permissions-issue-md), suggests instead that Homebrew be  uninstalled/reinstalled after the upgrade to High Sierra.

I successfully used @aether2501's reinstall command, `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`, on High Sierra (10.13.2) without uninstalling brew first.

In addition to creating the /usr/local/Frameworks directory and setting the necessary ownership and permissions I needed to link python3, it also appears to have fixed other directory issues.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and used:

```
sudo -H pip3 install virtualenv
sudo -H pip3 install virtualenvwrapper --ignore-installed six
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add my own solution to this exact problem.

On MacOS [specifically Ventura] I did `brew install python` - it turns out homebrew *does* actually install `pip`, but the difference is that the *actual* command to use is now `pip3` instead of "pip".

As a result, I aliased the command `pip` to equal `pip3` by adding this line to my `.zshrc` (though if you are working with a bash shell, it'll work as well):

`alias pip="pip3"`

When the time comes that pip moves to a ver.4, I'll have to update this, but for now, it has solved my issue without any further linking or PATH changes.