# brew install python3, but can't link to python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to install `python3` via `brew`

```
==> Downloading https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.4/Python-3.6.4.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/leongaban/Library/Caches/Homebrew/python3-3.6.4.tar.xz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2 --enable-ipv6 --datarootdir=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/shar
==> make
==> make install PYTHONAPPSDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2
==> make frameworkinstallextras PYTHONAPPSDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/share/python3
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a4/c8/9a7a47f683d54d83f648d37c3e180317f80dc126a304c45dc6663246233a/se
Already downloaded: /Users/leongaban/Library/Caches/Homebrew/python3--setuptools-36.5.0.zip
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/11/b6/abcb525026a4be042b486df43905d6893fb04f05aac21c32c638e939e447/pi
Already downloaded: /Users/leongaban/Library/Caches/Homebrew/python3--pip-9.0.1.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fa/b4/f9886517624a4dcb81a1d766f68034344b7565db69f13d52697222daeb72/wh
Already downloaded: /Users/leongaban/Library/Caches/Homebrew/python3--wheel-0.30.0.tar.gz

Error: An unexpected error occurred during the `brew link` step
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks
Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks
➜  ~ python -V
Python 2.7.10
➜  ~ brew link python3 
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2... Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks
```

I found this answer, following the steps, but still running into the problem where I can't link python3 and my `python -V` still shows `2.7`

[brew install python3 didn't install pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47255517/brew-install-python3-didnt-install-pip3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
```

This will give permission to create the symlinks, hence solving the issue with linking.

Comment: this breaks brew on systems with multiple users who `brew`, does it not?

Comment: When I try this I get the error `chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted`. Any ideas why?

Comment: After that I tried making the directory manually (`sudo mkdir /usr/local/Frameworks`) and then changing the permissions on the new directory (`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Frameworks`). This allowed me finally to run `brew link python` without error.

Answer (score 0):

AH! I just fixed it, I had created the Frameworks folder inside of `/usr/local/lib` instead of just `/usr/local/`

After moving the folder and re-running
`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`

I'm able to `brew link python3`

Answer (score 0):

I'm copying the comment from @lucas here for more visibility. This worked for me.

1. Manually create the Frameworks directory.

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/Frameworks
```

2. Change the permissions on the new directory.

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Frameworks
```

3. Run the `brew link` command to complete the symlink.

```
brew link python3
```